# Git ignore particular change to file but track all future changes to that file

Tags: git

I want Git to ignore a change to a particular section of a tracked file  but to then  carry on tracking all future changes to same file.

Is it possible to do this in Git?

I am aware that to ignore a change to tracked file:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged config/database.yml
```

But this ignore all future changes to said file. I however still need the file to be change.

The reason why i need to do this is that I have placed particular configuration in the local file that is only relevant to my local branch.

Comment: You'd have to describe your context a bit further for us to understand why you don't just selectively `add` what you need, leaving what you don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this file from your git  repo but add a generic example of what the `database.yml` file should look like, let's call it `database.yml.example`.

You can remove the file from your repository using :

```
git rm --cached config/database.yml
```

Do a copy of your `database.yml` to `database.yml.example`, removing any specific data and add it to your repo.

When you need to modify the `database.yml.example` file, you'll need to update local `database.yml` files by including the changes that were made to `database.yml.example`.